# What does "offset" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Judge Judy reading from a police report:

> I then observe a small drop of blood on the shirt of Ohr... Thompson was standing behind Ohr and slightly **offset**. ([source](https://youtu.be/Keakn8aQ-JM?t=1974))

"Offset" strikes me as strange in this context. It seems to describe a person as being off-balance and under the influence. But according to major dictionaries, "offset" is not an adjective and doesn't mean what it is used to mean in these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context *slightly offset* means slightly to one side as opposed to directly behind.